# How to change png image pixel value using php

Tags: php

Am trying change white pixel to black in image but i am have difficulties with setting color format for `imagesetpixel`

what am doing

```
// get image data
$image_data = imagecreatefrompng($image);

// Turn off alpha blending
imagealphablending($image_data, false);

$width = imagesx($image_data);
$height = imagesy($image_data);

for($x = 0; $x < $width; $x++) {
    for($y = 0; $y < $height; $y++) {
        // pixel color at (x, y)
       $color = imagecolorsforindex($image_data, imagecolorat($image_data, $x, $y)); // human readable
        // check if we have white
        if(
            $color['red'] == 255 &&
            $color['green'] == 255 &&
            $color['blue'] == 255 &&
            $color['alpha'] == 127
        ){    
            //  make it black
            $color['red'] == 0
            $color['green'] == 0
            $color['blue'] == 0 
            imagesetpixel($image_data, $x, $y, $color );  // $color format not OK.
        } 
    }
}

    // Set alpha flag
    imagesavealpha($image_data, true);  
    //  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php
    imagepng($image_data , "path to save png");
    imagedestroy($image_data);
```

so any idea how we can convert `imagecolorsforindex` return format to be compatible with `imagesetpixel`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```php
//  make it black
$color['red'] == 0
$color['green'] == 0
$color['blue'] == 0 
imagesetpixel($image_data, $x, $y, $color );  // $color format not OK.
```

Does not follow the [`imagesetpixel`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagesetpixel.php) style as the error indicates:

> Uncaught TypeError: imagesetpixel(): Argument #4 ($color) must be of type int, array given

---

Lets's fix that, consider the following example:

```php
// Create black color (rgb)
$black = imagecolorallocate($image_data, 0, 0, 0);

// Make it black
imagesetpixel($image_data, $x, $y, $black);
```

Here we're using [`imagecolorallocate`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorallocate.php)  to create the 'black' which `imagesetpixel` accepts as a color.
The `$image_data`, `x` and `y` were just fine, we'll keep them as they are.

---

Also, I created a simple test image to check if it's working, however, your check didn't trigger for a simple white pixel created by MacOs preview, the `alpha` was set to `0`, so for my testing I'd make the following changes:

```php
if(
    $color['red'] == 255 &&
    $color['green'] == 255 &&
    $color['blue'] == 255 // &&
    // $color['alpha'] == 127
)
```